# Hide ribbon in a modal pop up dialog

Tags: 2013, ribbon

I'm having an issue trying to hide the ribbon when the modal displays as a pop up.

Here is what I have tried so far.
Within the JavaScript I call this

```
function MyJSMethodWithCallBack() {
    var dialogOptions = {
        url: 'newpage.aspx',
        dialogReturnValueCallback: function (dialogResult) {
            //Where you can do additional JS function base on the dialogResult.
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult);
        }
    };
    OpenPopUpPageWithDialogOptions(dialogOptions);
    HideRibbon();
}

function HideRibbon() {
    $('.ms-dlgFrame').load(function () {
        console.log("This enters the Hide Button");
        $('#s4-ribbonrow').hide();
    });
}
```

The comment within hide-button does get displayed, but the ribbon is still displaying.
This is a webpart page in sharepoint 2013. I'm guessing the page is loading before the hide can occur? What should I do differently?

Comment: Try appending ?isDlg=1 to the url

Comment: You should place the code that hide the ribbon in the page you display (newpage.aspx), and invoke it for example from $(document).ready(), or at least, wait in your current implementation till the page in the modal dialog is loaded an the ribbon is rendered (for example via a DOM event or setTimout method). If you use the same newpage.aspx from other context as well, and you need the ribbon there, you can append a query string parameter to the URL (like newpage.aspx?hideribbon=1) and hide the ribbon depending on that parameter.

Comment: to hide ribbon from popup, you just need to add "s4-notdlg" class to ribbon like this <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-notdlg">

Answer (score 6):

Add following css in your newpage.aspx, this way the ribbon will only be hidden in dialog view, and still usable in normal view.

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .ms-dialog #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-dialog .ms-cui-topBar2, .ms-dialog .s4-notdlg, .ms-dialog .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .ms-dialog .s4-notdlg noindex, .ms-dialog #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, .ms-dialog #s4-titlerow, .ms-dialog #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, .ms-dialog #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}
    .ms-dialog .s4-ca{margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}
    </style>
```